# error :404 not found with jquery and servlet

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

i want to send data from html page to the servlet, i use jquery and a post request, the error is :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found),i tried to change the url in the post request but i had the same error.

index.html

```
 <body>
    <form id="form">
      <p><input type="text"  id="name"></p> 
       <p> <input type="button" value="test servlet" id="test"  ></p>  
        <div id="res"></div> 
    </form></body>
```

test.js

```
 $("#test").click(function (){
var n = $("#name").val();    
   $.post("controller/Test.java",{name:n},function(data){

         $("#res").html(data);
   });
```

package:controller,Test.java

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   String a ;
a = request.getParameter("name");

 out.println("welcome" +a);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely wrong

```
$.post("controller/Test.java",{name:n},function(data){
```

Servlets has to be mapped first into URL path, traditionally this is done via web.xml.

I suggest you revisit java servlet basic: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html

Comment: thanks  gerrytan, but i don't understand what do you mean ? in my web.xml file i find <servlet-class>controller.Test</servlet-class> and i replaced it in the post request but same error

Comment: thanks for the link, i find the solution